# Error in SQL Syntax when trying to insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a piece of code that allows users to send messages to each other. Whenever I try to insert the message into the database, I get a syntax error, but I, for the life of me, cannot figure out what my error is. I know that the issue is not within `connect.php`. Also, I am getting the appropriate values for `$from`, `$to`, and `$message` so that can't be the issue. Here is my code:

```
session_start();

require_once('../setup/connect.php');

$from = $_SESSION['id'];
$to = $_REQUEST['id'];

$message = trim($_POST['msg_body']);    
$insert = "INSERT INTO messages(to, from, msg) VALUES('$to', '$from', '$message')";

mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: view_profile.php?id=$to");
```

Here is the report `mysql_error()` generates:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL    server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'to, from, msg) VALUES('7', '6', 'Hey how are you?')' at line
>   1

And here is an image of my database structure:[image]

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I noticed your msg column uses varchar(2000). It might be more efficient to change it to TEXT instead. Just a suggestion!

Comment: This code needs a lesson from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Comment: @ShawnCheever: I suggest that if there's not a specific, measurable win in changing from VARCHAR to TEXT, the "more efficient" is a premature optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TO` and `FROM` are reserved keywords, it must be escaped with backtick

```
INSERT INTO messages(`to`, `from`, msg) 
VALUES('$to', '$from', '$message')
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have time or privilege to alter, don't use such names that are present on the reserved keyword list. It will give you future head aches.

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` is a reserved word. You shouldn't use it as a column name. If you insist on using it you have to quote it:

```
INSERT INTO messages("to", "from", msg) 
VALUES('$to', '$from', '$message')
```

or if you are not running your MySQL installation in ANSI mode you will have to use the dreaded non-standard backticks:

```
INSERT INTO messages(`to`, `from`, msg) 
VALUES('$to', '$from', '$message')
```

Comment: I think you mean "FROM is a reserved word. You should NOT use it as a column name" ? Quite right.

Comment: @VinnyRoe: absolutely. Thanks.